# generar 2 o más números aleatorios entre 1 y 10 en javascript sin repetirse

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como podria hacer un generador de números aleatorios con javascript donde yo ingrese la cantidad de numeros resultantes que quiero por ejemplo:

Ingreso que quiero 3 "numeros ganadores" entre el rango de 0 a 20 por ejemplo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
    const results = [];
    const limit = 2;
    
    // mientras sea menor al limite
    while (results.length < limit) {
        // obtenemos un número aleatorio entre 0 y 10
     const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
      
      // Lo agregamos al arreglo si el numero no existe en el listado
      if (!results.includes(number)) {
       results.push(number);
      }
    }
    
    console.log("RESULTS: ", results);
```